# HTTP build query with PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 before PHP 5.4

Tags: php, http

I thought I would be able to use the easy `http_build_query` to encode some GET parameters from an array, but apparently the `enc_type` seems to have been added in PHP 5.4. Unfortunately I'm on PHP 5.3.10.

Problem is that I need the parameters encoded with spaces being `%20` and not `+`. Any good nice quick solutions of encoding the parameters correctly without using `http_build_query`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the URL is encoded when `http_build_query` returns, so that `+` are always and only spaces, you can just chain it with `str_replace`:

```
$query = str_replace('+', '%20', http_build_query($arr));
```

If you don't want to encode the `~` as well:

```
$query = str_replace(
    array('+', '%7E'), 
    array('%20', '~'), 
    http_build_query($arr)
);
```

Comment: But will other characters be encoded correctly then? Or is it just the spaces which are different?

Comment: Obviously, no. But there are few differences in encoding between 1738 and 3986. From what I can see, the only other one, as far as PHP is concerned, is the tilde `~` than should stay as-is in 3986.

Answer (score 3):

You can use de PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 flag.

```
$query = http_build_query($query_data, null, null, PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

Comment: Include '&'. like so:  `$query = http_build_query($query_data, null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);`

Comment: 1) the question was about doing that *before PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 was added*, 2) passing `null` as 2nd parameter is no longer valid ATM.

Answer (score 1):

You could also pass the query string through the rawurlencode function.  Available in 5.3 it encodes to RFC 3986:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more concise version of @cwd's answer.

```
public function httpBuildQuery3986(array $params, $sep = '&')
{
    $parts = array();
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $parts[] = sprintf('%s=%s', $key, rawurlencode($value));
    }

    return implode($sep, $parts);
}
```

Comment: Won't work for multi dimensional $params. ($value might be an array)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at a function for PHP 5.3 to build a `RFC 3986` query string.

```
// build query strings with RFC 3986 encoding for PHP < 5.4
// does not have $numeric_prefix or $enc_type options
// note per the rawurlencode man page:
// Prior to PHP 5.3.0, rawurlencode encoded tildes (~) as per » RFC 1738.

function http_build_query_rfc_3986($query_data,$arg_separator='&')
{
    $r = '';
    $query_data = (array) $query_data;
    if(!empty($query_data))
    {
        foreach($query_data as $k=>$query_var)
        {
            $r .= $arg_separator;
            $r .= $k;
            $r .= '=';
            $r .= rawurlencode($query_var);
        }
    }
    return trim($r,$arg_separator);

}
```

Comment: Won't work for multi dimensional $params. ($query_var might be an array)